# canvas.toJSON() not work in localhost

Tags: javascript, localhost, fabricjs

In jsfiddle

http://jsfiddle.net/gislef/fvzj7z1d/1/

```
 document.getElementById('jsson').onclick = function() {
    canvas.includeDefaultValues = false;
    json = canvas.toJSON();
    alert(JSON.stringify(json));

    };
```

This part:

```
json = canvas.toJSON();
```

Works perfectly

But with same code in local host, all works less canvas.toJSON();

I do not know what happens

**EDITED**

I´m using library Fabricjs, the `canvas.toJSON()` have all items (images, text, etc) added in canvas, of course in json format.

Comment: Look at the Console in your browser's developer tools. What does it say?

Comment: You haven't given enough information to really get a good answer to this question, I would advise posting more info on what you've tried, output from your dev tools, etc. for better responses.

Comment: @TrevorHart Thank you, I added information in my question

Comment: @Quentin No appear error at the console

Answer (score 1):

Are you running it on a HTTP server, or just opening the file in the browser (`file://`)? `.toJSON()`, `toDataUri()` etc. only work on a HTTP server ([source](http://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/canvas/integrating/#toc-exporting)), so you would have to start a quick http server, e.g. with `python -m SimpleHTTPServer 8000`.

Comment: Thank you @spacek33z. I´m using wamp server at the local host. I understand that wamp using http

Comment: I´m using library Fabricjs, canvas.toJSON() have all items (images, text, etc) added in canvas,  of course in json format,